# Unable to write a reference to LoginComponent in /Users/lib/pages/login/login.component.ts from /Users/lib/users.module.ts

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to build the application but another error came up... I've checked the app and it's working. Also looked up on the internet for several days and tried all of the methods people used and it's still giving me the error... Please help! Thank you in advance!

repo structure:

```
├── users
│   ├── src
│   │   ├── lib
│   │   │   ├── pages
│   │   │   │   ├── login
│   │   │   │       ├── login.component.html
│   │   │   │       ├── login.component.ts
│   │   │   ├── users.module.ts
```

login.component.ts:

```
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';
import { LocalstorageService } from '../../services/localstorage.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'users-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styles: [
  ]
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  loginFormGroup: FormGroup;
  isSubmitted = false;
  autError = false;
  authMessage = 'Email or Password are wrong';
  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private auth: AuthService,
    private localstorageService: LocalstorageService,
    private router : Router
    
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._initLoginForm();
  }

  private _initLoginForm() {
    this.loginFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      password: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.isSubmitted = true;

    if(this.loginFormGroup.invalid) {
      return;
    }
    this.auth.login(this.loginForm.email.value, this.loginForm.password.value).subscribe(
    (user) => {
      this.autError = false;
      this.localstorageService.setToken(user.token);
      this.router.navigate(['/']);
    }, 
    (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      this.autError = true;
      if(error.status !== 400) {
        this.authMessage = 'Error in server, try again later!';
      }
    });
  }

  get loginForm() {
    return this.loginFormGroup.controls;
  }
}
```

users.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './pages/login/login.component';
import { InputTextModule } from 'primeng/inputtext';
import { ButtonModule } from 'primeng/button';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import { EffectsModule } from '@ngrx/effects';
import * as fromUsers from './state/users.reducer';
import { UsersEffects } from './state/users.effects';
import { UsersFacade } from './state/users.facade';



const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        RouterModule.forChild(routes),
        InputTextModule,
        ButtonModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        StoreModule.forFeature(fromUsers.USERS_FEATURE_KEY, fromUsers.reducer),
        EffectsModule.forFeature([UsersEffects])
    ],
    declarations: [LoginComponent],

    providers: [UsersFacade]
})
export class UsersModule {}
```

tsconfig.base.json:

```
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noImplicitReturns": false,
        "strictNullChecks": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
        "rootDir": ".",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "importHelpers": true,
        "target": "es2015",
        "module": "esnext",
        "lib": ["es2017", "dom"],
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "@env/*": ["environments/*"],
            "@eshopapp/orders": ["libs/orders/src/index.ts"],
            "@eshopapp/products": ["libs/products/src/index.ts"],
            "@eshopapp/ui": ["libs/ui/src/index.ts"],
            "@eshopapp/users": ["libs/users/src/index.ts"]
        }
    },
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "tmp"]
}
```

Comment: Can we see your tsconfig ? What's the rootDir ?

Comment: I have update tsconfig.base.json code on. 
`"rootDir": "."`

Comment: Are you using nx ? (nrwl) I am guessing so here based on your tsconfig,

Could you share as well your repo structure ? Like under user, just to make sure we aren't missing something obvious here. I might try to throw a way as well to reproduce the issue in case

Comment: Yes I using nx. I have post repo structure on. I don't have any idea why it error.

Comment: going to need more details to help here. I've setup a repo locally to reproduce but no errors on my side. Could you, by any chance link to a github or small reproduce for that so I can help you further ? 

My wild guess here is something potentially to do with some of the imports inside your login component or your users.module. You could otherwise try to isolate the issue by commenting some of your imports / code and try to build to see which part is causing the issue